# Is it is possible to convert query on postgresql database to geopackage file

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis, geopackage

I am working on postgresql database with postgis. 
I was generate csv file from the database which includes geo information but I need now to generate geopackage file instead.
I searched on this but I did not found any tools making something like that directly.
I know I can use gdal to convert from csv to geopackage file but I do not need to make that. I need to generate the geopackage file direct from the database. 
Can anyone help me in that?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

gdal support also generate geopackage file from the table/view direct using command like the following:

```bash
ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" mynewfilename.gpkg \
PG:"host=localhost user=postgres dbname=postgres password=mypassword" "mytablename"
```

Answer (score 1):

In theory: yes, it *could* be done. But in reality: it's almost impossible.

The geopackage file format is based on the SQLite one's. In PostgreSQL you can connect to different databases (in case of SQLite: to files) through [foreign data wrappers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createforeigndatawrapper.html). There is an [SQLite foreign data wrapper](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers#sqlite_fdw), but it's only read-only. There is also a [JDBC wrapper](https://github.com/atris/JDBC_FDW/blob/master/README), which *can* support SQLite. But even if you can manage to write a new SQLite database file from PostgreSQL, you will need to study geopackage's internal format -- with just a "Coming soon" Implementation Guide (as of writing).

Comment: Interesting, I had never heard of the geopackage format until today. This does not answer the OP's question, but Geoserver has implemented a geopackage plugin that allows wfs, wms, etc to be returned in geopackage format: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/geopkg/index.html

Comment: @JohnBarça I agree, the right way to do is to use an "official" program/plugin to convert OP's data to the geopackage format. My answer only clarifies that this is almost (but **not**) impossible from within PostgreSQL itself.